# Laravel 7 how to install a language

Tags: laravel, localization

I am trying to install the French language in my Laravel application. I started with

```
composer require laravel-lang/lang:~6.1
```

Then I was plunged into perplexity by this directive given on Github site

> After adding the dependency using composer (as described above) to
> your application you can find the language files under the directory
> vendor/laravel-lang/lang.

> Copy the folders (and JSON files) of languages that you want to use,
> into the directory resources/lang of your Laravel application

I am trying to explain why.

In the resources/lang folder I already have this structure:

```
resources
    lang
        en
            auth.php
            pagination.php
            password.php
            validation.php
```

and in the vendor/laravel-lang folder this one:

```
laravel-lang
    lang
        json
            many json files including fr.jison
        src
            many folder other than fr
            fr
               auth.php
               pagination.php
               password.php
               validation.php
        script
            en
                auth.php
                pagination.php
                password.php
                validation.php
                en.json
```

Despite my perplexity in front of the abstruse directive (which is rarely the case in the laravel documentation) I copied the fr folder found under laravel-lang/lang/script/fr into resources/lang and added to its content the fr.json file found under laravel-lang/lang/json folder.
To fully comply with what I saw in the larave/-lang/lang folder I also added to the resources/lang/en folder the en.json file.

After that I changed the locale declaration in my config/app.ph file

```
  'locale' => 'fr',
```

and after restarting and doing

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

I still have the GUI in English for example

Reset Password, E_mail address, Send Passord Reset Link in the reset password request form.

What did I miss?

Comment: Pretty confusing question, the documentation of the package explains pretty well how to use it in my opinion. Did you copy [this](https://github.com/Laravel-Lang/lang/blob/master/json/fr.json) file into `resources/lang` so you have `resources/lang/fr.json` right now?

Comment: Yes I did and I have the fr.json file as well as others like described in my initial post.

Comment: But it comes from what has been installed by composer i.e. laravel-lang/lang/json/fr.json

Comment: Could you add how the directory structure currently looks? You mention the following: _"To fully comply with what I saw in the larave/-lang/lang folder I also added to the resources/lang/en folder the en.json file"_ this is wrong and not how the Laravel localization works, the file should be in the `resources/lang` directory, so `resources/lang/en.json`

Comment: You are right. I misunderstood the directive. I moved the jison file and now it works correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You moved the json translation files into the wrong directory.

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/localization#using-translation-strings-as-keys):

> Translation files that use translation strings as keys are stored as
> JSON files in the `resources/lang` directory. For example, if your
> application has a Spanish translation, you should create a
> `resources/lang/es.json` file:

```
{
    "I love programming.": "Me encanta programar."
}
```

So in your case move the json translation files from `resources/lang/en` and `resources/lang/fr` to `resources/lang`:

- `resources/lang/fr.json`
- `resources/lang/en.json`